# How to generate dynamic id using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add progressive id to a series of elements on an unordered HTML list. I used the jQuery `.each()` method to get each `<li>` of the List and append a `<span>` inside each `<li>`. Then I added the ID attribute with index of each() as number.

```
$('#menu li ul li').each(function(i, e){
    $(this).append('<span class="arr"></span>');
    $(".arr").attr("id", "id_" + i);
});
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/NZgyD/)</kbd>

But I get `id_3` for all elements. Why? What did I do wrong?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What problem would adding the ids solve?

Comment: `$(this).append('<span class="arr"></span>').attr("id", "id_" + i)` or `$(this).append('<span class="arr" id="id_'+i+'"></span>')` will do what you want ... `$(".arr").attr("id", "id_" + i)` will set the same i to all arr class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As has been pointed out, `$(".arr")` targets every element with the `arr` class, so on the fourth iteration you update all such elements to the `id_3` id.

You can limit the selection with `$(".arr", this)` or `$(this).find(".arr")`, but it would be easier to just turn the append around:

```
$('#menu li ul li').each(function(i, e){
    $('<span class="arr"></span>')
        .attr("id", "id_" + i)
        .appendTo(this);
});
```

That is, create the element first, set its id, then use [`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/) instead of `.append()`.

Or rather than calling `.attr()` you can pass the desired attributes directly to the [`$()` function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-attributes) when you create your span:

```
$('#menu li ul li').each(function(i, e){
    $('<span></span>', {
        "class": "arr",
        "id": "id_" + i
    }).appendTo(this);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your very comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 7):

It is because you are applying it to `.arr` globally, so overriding it every time.
You need to be more specific with adding it, by finding the `.arr` in you current `li`.

Change your code to be:

```
$('#menu li ul li').each(function(i, e){
    $(this).append('<span class="arr"></span>');
    $(this).find(".arr").attr("id", "id_" + i);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You are targeting a class when assigning the attribute. Every element you create is created with the same class so all items get assigned the same attribute. This code saves the newly created element to a variable called elem and then sets the attribute ID of that newly created element.

```
var elem = $(this).append('<span class="arr"></span>');
elem.attr("id", "id_" + i);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to scope your `$(".arr").attr("id", "id_" + i);` selector. Its currently pulling all the `<span>` tags each time. I'm guessing you have 4 total at this point, which is why they are all getting set to "id_3".

Added in $(this) to your selector.

> `$('#menu li ul li').each(function(i, e){
>       $(this).append('<span class="arr"></span>');
>       $(".arr", this).attr("id", "id_" + i);
>    });`

Modified Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NZgyD/2/

Comment: Wouldn't `$(".arr",this)` do the trick? No need to wrap `this` with `$()`.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it this way

```
$('#menu li ul li').each(function(i, e){
    $(this).append('<span id="id_' + i + '" class="arr"></span>');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

because `$(".arr")` is selector for multiple items

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Łukasz웃Lツ - It answers the question (which was "Why? What did I do wrong?"), just not in a very comprehensive way. But for some people just knowing what they did wrong would be enough for them to fix the problem themselves...